# Perl HTML::Tokeparser get raw html between tags

Tags: perl, html-parsing

i am using TokeParser to extract tag contents.

```
...
$text = $p->get_text("/td") ;
...
```

usually it will return the text cleaned up. What I want is to return everthing between `td` and `/td` but including all other html elements. How to do that.

I am using the example in [this tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=99254). thanks

In the example,

```
my( $tag, $attr, $attrseq, $rawtxt) = @{ $token };
```

I believe there is some trick to do with `$rawtxt` .

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with HTML::Tokeparser, why not use regex to capture your data?

Comment: try to use `get_tag("td")` and then "Dump" the result, I think it will have the data you seek, but not sure

Comment: It's really a challenging task. Better to try with a `DOM` parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML::TokeParser does not have a built-in feature to do this. However, it's possible by looking at each token between `<td>`s individually.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
use HTML::TokeParser;
use 5.012;

# dispatch table with subs to handle the different types of tokens
my %dispatch = (
  S  => sub { $_[0]->[4] }, # Start tag
  E  => sub { $_[0]->[2] }, # End tag
  T  => sub { $_[0]->[1] }, # Text
  C  => sub { $_[0]->[1] }, # Comment
  D  => sub { $_[0]->[1] }, # Declaration
  PI => sub { $_[0]->[2] }, # Process Instruction
);

# create the parser
my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new( \*DATA ) or die "Can't open: $!";

# fetch all the <td>s
TD: while ( $p->get_tag('td') ) {
  # go through all tokens ...
  while ( my $token = $p->get_token ) {
    # ... but stop at the end of the current <td>
    next TD if ( $token->[0] eq 'E' && $token->[1] eq 'td' );
    # call the sub corresponding to the current type of token
    print $dispatch{$token->[0]}->($token);
  }
} continue {
  # each time next TD is called, print a newline
  print "\n";  
}

__DATA__
<html><body><table>
<tr>
<td><strong>foo</strong></td>
<td><em>bar</em></td>
<td><font size="10"><font color="#FF0000">frobnication</font></font>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amet fooofooo foo.</p></td>
</tr></table></body></html>
```

This program will parse the HTML document in the `__DATA__` section and print everything including HTML between `<td>` and `</td>`. It will print one line per `<td>`. Let's go through it step by step.

- After reading the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser), I learned that each token from HTML::TokeParser has a type associated with it. There are six types: `S`, `E`, `T`, `C`, `D` and `PI`. The doc says:

  > This method will return the next token found in the HTML document, or
  >   undef at the end of the document. The token is returned as an array
  >   reference. The first element of the array will be a string denoting
  >   the type of this token: "S" for start tag, "E" for end tag, "T" for
  >   text, "C" for comment, "D" for declaration, and "PI" for process
  >   instructions. The rest of the token array depend on the type like
  >   this:
  >
  > ```
  > ["S",  $tag, $attr, $attrseq, $text]
  > ["E",  $tag, $text]
  > ["T",  $text, $is_data]
  > ["C",  $text]
  > ["D",  $text]
  > ["PI", $token0, $text]
  > ```
- We want to access the `$text` stored in these tokens, because there is no other way to grab stuff that looks like HTML tags. I therefore created a [dispatch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) to handle them in `%dispatch`. It stores a bunch of code refs that get called later.
- We read the document from `__DATA__`, which is convenient for this example.
- First of all, we need to fetch the `<td>`s by using the `get_tag` method. @nrathaus's comment pointed me that way. It will move the parser to the next token after the opening `<td>`. We don't care about what `get_tag` returns since we only want the tokens after the `<td>`.
- We use the method `get_token` to fetch the next token and do stuff with it:

  - But we only want to do that until we find the corresponding closing `</td>`. If we see that, we `next` the outer `while` loop labelled `TD`.
  - At that point, the [`continue` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html) gets called and prints a newline.
  - If we are not at the end, the magic happens: the dispatch table; As we saw earlier, the first element in the token array ref holds the type. There is a code ref for each of these types in `%dispatch`. We call it and pass the complete array ref `$token` by going `$coderef->(@args)`. We print the result on the current line.

    This will produce stuff like `<strong>`, `foo`, `</strong>` and so on in each run.

Please note that this will only work for one table. If there is a table within a table (something like `<td> ... <td></td> ... </td>`) this will break. You would have to adjust it to take remember of how many levels deep it is.

---

Another approach would be to use miyagawa's excellent [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web%3a%3aScraper). That way, we have a lot less code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
use Web::Scraper;
use 5.012;

my $s = scraper {
  process "td", "foo[]" => 'HTML'; # grab the raw HTML for all <td>s
  result 'foo'; # return the array foo where the raw HTML is stored
};

my $html = do { local $/ = undef; <DATA> }; # read HTML from __DATA__
my $res = $s->scrape( $html ); # scrape

say for @$res; # print each line of HTML
```

This approach can also handle multi-dimensional tables like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a fun task. :) What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: well, i kinda like tokeparser. With so many such modules in CPAN, i really get headaches trying to choose one. So i just try to stick to one parsing tool, at least just for now. I am trying to change the tags nested inside td to a delimiter.